# Authorization Header not set for cross domain request

Tags: jquery, rest, basic-authentication

I read various posts but could not figure out the solution.
I am calling this url http://somesite.com/test.html and
code in test.html is

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://anothersite.com/app_dev.php/rest/123",
  crossDomain: true,
  async: false,
  beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
    alert('Befor Sent');
    var text = btoa("11" + ":" + "22");
    alert("Enc:" + text);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + text); 

 },
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("errorThrown:" + errorThrown);
},
 success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
 }
```

});

I get 401 error back and when I check headers there is no Authorization header

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens if the code is run on browser. I tried this for phonegap and it works perfectly.